ASAuthorizationController AuthorizationError Code=1004 "(null)", when trying to access iOS biometric authentication
so I am working in an app in flutter that is using inappwebview, this is a simple navigator in the app to allow users to access the web platform directly from a native app (A company request).
The app that is trying to be accessed has biometric authentication as an option to grant access to the user.
The problem is that the app does not have permission to access biometric credentials and i dont know how to grant them. I have added signin cappabilities to All (Release, debug and profile) stages in xcode and also the NSFaceIDUsageDescription to the Info.plist.
This is the error that xcode shows when clicking on activate in the flutter app.
ASAuthorizationController credential request failed with error: Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1004 "(null)"

The app error

The expected behavior, this is what happen then trying to access from a normal browser and click on "activate"

This is the flutter code to launch the inappwebview
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class HomePageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageWidget({super.key});

  @override
  _HomePageWidgetState createState() => _HomePageWidgetState();
}

class _HomePageWidgetState extends State<HomePageWidget> {
  late MyInAppBrowser browser;
  final settings = InAppBrowserClassSettings(
      browserSettings: InAppBrowserSettings(
          hideToolbarBottom: true,
          hideCloseButton: true,
          hideUrlBar: true,
          hideTitleBar: true,
          hideDefaultMenuItems: true,
          presentationStyle: ModalPresentationStyle.OVER_FULL_SCREEN),
      webViewSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
      
        userAgent: Platform.isAndroid
            ? "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 14) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.6367.82 Mobile Safari/537.36"
            : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.4.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
        cacheEnabled: true,
        javaScriptEnabled: true,
        isElementFullscreenEnabled: true,
      ));
  // Assuming this is the correct type

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    browser = MyInAppBrowser(onBrowserExit: () {
      setState(() {
        // Handle browser exit if needed
      });
    });
    openBrowser();
  }

  void openBrowser() async {
    await browser.openUrlRequest(
        urlRequest: URLRequest(
            url: WebUri(
                "https://linktowebapp")), 
        settings: settings);
    // Additional logic if necessary
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Your build method as before, but replace the onPressed method:
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}

// Modify the MyInAppBrowser class to accept a callback
class MyInAppBrowser extends InAppBrowser {
  final VoidCallback onBrowserExit;

  MyInAppBrowser({required this.onBrowserExit});

  @override
  void onExit() {
    super.onExit();
    print("Browser closed!");
    onBrowserExit(); // Call the provided callback
  }

  // The rest of your MyInAppBrowser implementation...
}


Your question is actually relating to Passkeys, not biometric authentication per-se.  The NSFaceIDUsageDescription info.plist entry is related to use of the LocalAuthentication framework within your app (which you aren't doing).
Flutter's inappwebview uses iOS's WKWebView under the covers.
Apple has provided instructions to support Passkeys in WKWebView:

To authenticate using passkeys in a WKWebView web view, configure your service’s relying party identifier as an associated domain in your app. For more information, see Supporting associated domains.

You will need to obtain the relying party identifier from the web site and add it to your info.plist file as an associated domain.

Hello Paul, thank you for your response. I have added the <key>Associated Domains</key>  to the Info.plist with every possible domain that can be associated with the requests in the authentication and also the associated domains to the sign in cappabilities with the same domains but still giving the same error. Also added the keychain sharing in the sign in cappabilities, do you have a clue what could be the problem?

Did you add literally "Associated Domains"? The key is com.Apple.developer.associated-domains and the value is an array of string. That isn't correct https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains and you don't need to add "every possible domain". You need to find the specific domain that is listed in the rp of the PublicKeyCredentialOptions
